# Find duplicate rows in database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How do find duplicate rows? If last_name is the duplicate field, I want to have to display

```
last_name frst_name frst_name1 frst_name2 ....
```

Any database will do, prefer oracle.

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: Each database has its own recipe, but these are database specific.

Comment: I mean different tricks to get one copy, but details as row_id, row_num differ. But I misinterpreted the OP's question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your server has GROUP_CONCAT because you didn't mention which one you're using:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(first_name SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM table
GROUP BY last_name
HAVING COUNT(first_name) > 1
```

Comment: I like this a lot! For now, though, `GROUP_CONCAT` is only implemented in MySQL. There's an Oracle version at the following link, and the same blog has versions for PostGreSQL and SQL Server, too. http://explainextended.com/2009/04/05/group_concat-in-oracle-10g/

Comment: @eksortso: SQLite also supports the GROUP_CONCAT function.

Answer (score 14):

This should work on pretty much every SQL dialect:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name FROM names
WHERE last_name IN (
    SELECT last_name FROM names GROUP BY last_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

It will give you a result set like this, though:

```
Smith     Jack
Smith     Joe
Smith     Anna
Sixpack   Joe
Sixpack   Eve
```

The most elegant solution for displaying this in the desired format IMO is to just re-arrange the result set programmatically in the client application instead of pulling all sorts of obscure SQL stunts; something like (pseudocode):

```
for each row in resultset
   if row[last_name] <> previous_last_name
      print newline, print last_name
   print ' '
   print first_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Ha, lots of queries. Here is more

```
SELECT last_name, first_name FROM names n1
WHERE 
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM names n2 where n2.last_name = n1.last_name
) 
> 1
```

or if table has unique identifier

```
SELECT last_name, first_name FROM names n1
WHERE exists
(
    SELECT id FROM names n2 where n2.last_name = n1.last_name and n1.id <> n2.id
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select a.* from persons a inner join persons b on (a.personID<>b.PersonID and a.last_name=b.last_name)
```

PersonID is your table's primary key.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this is what you are asking for, but I think what you are looking for is

`SELECT * FROM users u1, users u2 
WHERE (u1.last_name = u2.last_name AND COUNT(u1.last_name) > 1))`

Comment: That would get you a lot of duplicates if you have a very popular last name.

Comment: I've just answered the question... If you would like to check the other fields as well, then you'll just have to add them in the WHERE clause with the DISTINCT option.

Comment: Can't use an aggregate (IE: COUNT) in the WHERE clause, outside of a subquery.  After you fixed that error, `SELECT *` would return rows from both copies of the `USERS` table

Answer (score 1):

I tried to devise a solution that would work in most ANSI-compliant SQL database servers. Here's what I came up with.

The idea here is that you identify the duplicated `last_name`s, then pull all the records that have one of those duplicates.

```
SELECT
   t.last_name, t.frst_name, t.frst_name1, t.frst_name2, ...
FROM our_table AS t
WHERE t.last_name IN (
   SELECT t0.last_name
   FROM our_table AS t0
   GROUP BY t0.last_name
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY
    t.last_name, t.frst_name, t.frst_name1, t.frst_name2, ...
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose "In table customer you have customerkey as PK" then you can use:

```
select 
    customerkey,count(customerkey) 
from 
    customer 
group 
    by customerkey
having 
    count(customerkey)>1;
```

This will give you all the duplicate customerkeys. Now you can delete them.