# Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one with names and telnumbers the second with calls

```
addressbook  name(VARCHAR) number(VARCHAR)

calls        date(DATE) number(VARCHAR) name(VARCHAR)
```

I want to update the names column in the calls table with the entries in the addressbook for the respective

```
UPDATE calls
SET name = ( SELECT name FROM addressbook WHERE number = calls.number )
WHERE DATE = "2020.01.01" 
ORDER BY DATE
```

And I get *Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Subquery returns more than 1 row* but there are no doublette in the addressbook I checked it several times.

Comment: There is at least one `calls.number` that appears at least twice in `addressbook`. You have a schema definition problem, a data validation problem, or both. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3773745/1707353) answer for a method that identifies duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, the sub query returns more than one row, a quick solution is:

```
SELECT name FROM addressbook WHERE number = calls.number LIMIT 1
```

if this solve the issue than the query return more than a row. If you need to returns just a row without using LIMIT 1 you should review your query adding more constraints or define a primary key for the addressbook table and continuing use your subquery as it is. This is on you.

Comment: This is a workaround that is likely to assign the wrong name to a given calls row. The OP thinks the primary key is name and number but doesn't realize the correlated subquery cannot know, given the schema, which name belongs to which number at a given point in time. I don't think you made the "this can do bad" statement strong enough in your answer. I think the OP might not know the implications of executing your answer.

Comment: @JeffHolt could you please elaborate this a little more I cannot follow you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way your update statement can fail with

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

is if there is at least one `calls` row whose number appears more than once in `addressbook`. You can find them with this query:

```
select number, count(*)
from addressbook
group by number
having count(*) > 1;
```

Let's say you have these two rows in `addressbook`:

```
name   number
------ ------
fred   123
barney 123
```

And let's say this is the row in `calls`:

```
date       name number
---------- ---- ------
2020.01.01 null 123
```

When you execute Stefano's update statement, the limit clause is not deterministic because there's no associated `order by` clause in the subquery. Nor is there any attribute common to `calls` and `addressbook` that would make it meaningful. The `order by` clause on the update is irrelevant. Therefore, you cannot guarantee which name will be assigned to the `calls` row. This is the point I was trying to make in my comment to Stefano's answer.

If the design of the system is to allow a number to be owned by multiple people over time (which they are of course), then your schema is not complete. And if that's true, then `addressbook` needs an effective date for the owner of the number.

If the design of the system is not to allow a number to be owned by multiple people over time, then you must delete the duplicate rows.

In either case, you need to do two things:

- employ declarative referential integrity constraints so you don't run afoul again
- stop updating `calls`: either insert (not update) the name or remove the column entirely

If I were to implement the tables of a telephony system, I would start with something like this:

```
create table PERSON (
       PERSON_ID          integer      not null primary key,
       NAME               varchar(100) not null /*lots of other columns*/);
create table PERSON_PHONE (
       PERSON_PHONE_ID    integer      not null primary key,
       PERSON_ID          integer      not null,
       PHONE_NUM          varchar(30)  not null,
       CONTRACTED         date         not null, /*lots of other columns*/
       unique (PERSON_ID, PHONE_NUM, CONTRACTED),
       foreign key (PERSON_ID) references PERSON(PERSON_ID));
create table PHONE_CALL (
       START_DATE         date         not null,
       END_DATE           date         not null,
       PERSON_PHONE_ID    integer      not null,
       primary key (PERSON_PHONE_ID, START_DATE),
       foreign key (PERSON_PHONE_ID) references PERSON_PHONE(PERSON_PHONE_ID));
```

---

It is true that sometimes, for the sake of making queries finish faster using fewer resources, people will sometimes denormalize a schema to decrease the number of join operations that would otherwise be required. Denormalization requires ***careful*** consideration.